# Implicit vector type cast for a custom class

Tags: c++, vector, casting, implicit

I have the following class:

```
class A
{       
    public: 

        A();
        A(uint64_t A);
        A(const A&) = default;

        operator uint64_t&() { return m_A; }
        operator const uint64_t& () const { return m_A; }

    private:

        uint64_t m_A;
};
```

With the following functions:

```
void Foo(const uint64_t& value);
void Bar(const std::vector <uint64_t>& value);
```

And as i have the () operator overload, when doing the following:

```
A a;

Foo(a);
```

The `Foo(a);` function call gets expectedly and correctly implicitly cast into

```
Foo(const uint64_t & a);
```

But when doing the following:

```
std::vector <A> aVector;

Bar(aVector);
```

it does not get implicitly cast into

```
Bar(const std::vector <uint64_t> & a);
```

which I want to happen.

What do I need to add so the
`std::vector <A> aVector` gets implicitly cast into `const std::vector <uint64_t> & aVector` ?

Comment: Implicit cast is impossible. You defined the cast A -> uint64_t, not vector<A> to vector<uint64_t>.

Comment: You might be able to achieve this with some disgusting type-punning hacks, but it's not recommended and the behavior would be undefined.

Comment: `vector<someTypeA>` and `vector<someTypeB>` are distinct and unrelated types, they are *NOT* interchangable, even if `someTypeA` and `someTypeB` are. `Bar()` takes a `vector` by (const) reference, so you need to satisfy the reference by using the *exact matching* type it wants - a `vector` of `uint64_t`s, not a `vector` of `A`s. On a side note, why is `A` implicitly converting to a `(const) uint64_t&` reference and not simply to `uint64_t` by value? `operator uint64_t() const { return m_A; }`